# com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException : The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I tried to search on google but failed to solve this issue.

I am trying to add Rest-Api within my Jsf application. for example if i call `http://localhost:5080/ApplicationFormFillingProcess-portlet/api/requirements`
i want to return JSON data.

so to handle these request i added one more servlet in my `web.xml` file. so now my **web.xml** file looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>redmond</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.infinite.npsc.Controller</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have this class `Controller.java` which is request scoped bean. Inside this class i have defined a method:- i.e

```
@Path("/api/requirements/")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TokenAndEbp getRequirementDetails(){

        final String loginUrl = "https://testserver.com/test/login";

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource(loginUrl);

        String input = "{\"username\":\"210003501a\",\"password\":\"123\"}";

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
           .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        System.out.println("the response code is:- "+response.getStatus());
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);

        String token = response.getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");
        System.out.println(token);

        TokenAndEbp tkp = new TokenAndEbp();
        tkp.setToken(token);
        tkp.setEbpCode("54454");
        return tkp;

    }
```

now when i call from postman `http://localhost:5080/ApplicationFormFillingProcess-portlet/api/requirements`

it simply shows the error which is :-

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:
The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
```

the list of dependencies i am currently using are:-

```
jersey-client-1.8
jersey-core-1.8
jersey-server-1.8
```